# Elegant solution to conditional AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing some javascript that includes a series AJAX calls and I am looking for an elegant solution to the following issue: The goal of the script is to gather parameters and then execute an API call with these parameters. The very first time the call is executed there is one parameter that needs to be requested from the server - every subsequent call will use a stored value of this parameter. This is where the issue begins. I want a conditional AJAX call to be made only if this is the first time. I don't want to put the rest of the code into the success function of that AJAX call as that seems convoluted. I would like something like the following but due to the obvious asynchronous nature of the call I realize this is not possible. I also want to avoid having a synchronous call as this would cause the thread to block:

```
var myParameter;

if(!params.myParam.isStored) {
    myParameter = getParamWithAjaxCall();
} else {
    myParameter = params.myParam;
}

// Continue with the rest of execution here of which there is a lot of code
```

Sorry if this seems like an obvious question and I have looked into solutions using the following but I am looking for an experienced opinion on what the most elegant solution would be:

jQuery: when.done

jQuery: async: false

Passing a callback to the Ajax call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a wrapper function which you pass your logic to as a callback in `done()`. Something like this:

```
function makeRequest(callback) {
    if (!params.myParam) {
        // retrieve param
        $.ajax({
            url: '/getParam',
            success: function(data) {
                params.myParam = data.param;
            } 
        }).done(callback);  
    }
    else {
        // param already has a value...
        callback();
    }
}

makeRequest(function() {
    // make your AJAX request here, knowing that params.myParam will have a value.
});
```

Comment: I really like this answer. It provides a good separation of concerns as well as being neat, elegant and easy to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use promises like so (I have used JQuery promises here):

```
function ParameterValueProvider() {

    var parameterValue;

    return function() {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        if ( parameterValue === undefined ) {
            $.ajax({
                // ... ajax parameters go here
            }).done(function(rsp) {
                parameterValue = rsp;
                deferred.resolve(parameterValue);
            });
        }

        deferred.resolve(parameterValue);

        return deferred;

    }

}

// Your Application
(function() {

    'use strict';

    var getParam = ParameterValueProvider();

    // this will get the value from server the firs time
    // and subsequent calls will use the cached value
    getParam().then(function() {
        // subsequent ajax calls go here
    });

}());
```

Comment: This was also a great answer but it just seems a bit more involved than @rory's. I need to look into promises to get a better understanding myself before I utilize them. Thank's a lot though!